# groovy kinect No Image received

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My laptop is [ASUS S46CM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ta01wxvv7hkbbv/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-14%2020_01_58.png)

When I `runlaunch turtlebot_rviz view-robot.launch`

this is environment.
[rviz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mvb0jmrbadlltm/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-14%2019_59_02.png)

Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60625/groovy-kinect-no-image-received/) by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem.
Just install Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit),and usb 3.0 can work.

---

Originally posted by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) with karma: 62 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, given all the previous comments, try the following solution :

go to [avin2 drivers](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/zipball/unstable).

Unpack, select the ones for your platform. Then use the "./uninstall" script first. Then "./install".

Try to launch again ""roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registered:=true". In another terminal, do a "rostopic list", and /camera/rgb/image_color should have appeared.

You are now free to quit everyting, and use your own application :

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch
```

then in another terminal

```
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz view-robot.launch
```

Let us know !

Ps : the solution comes from [this topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/60562/ubuntu-12042-and-openni_launch-not-detecting-kinect-after-update/?comment=60868#comment-60868)

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-04-17**:
I download this  but I don't know how to install.....   Please tell you,thanks

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-04-17**:
and uninstall.......

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to properly debug this problem more information is required. Please post information on what version/release of ROS you are running as well as a full list of the launch files along with any error messages.

Looking at the original information. So far here are my guess as to what might be wrong:

- I agree that it looks like the 3d_sensor.launch was not run. However I bet that when the 3dsensor.launch is run there is an error message that goes flying by that you are missing. Please scroll through the window and post a screenshot of any red/error text when launching.
- Also another cause might be that you just have a revision of ROS that was broken, at one point in groovy I encountered a bug which you could not get camera data caused by openni, the solution is to do an apt-get update on ROS.
- Are you running rviz remotely on desktop or locally on the turtlebot? Do you have your ROS IP set correctly? This might also be a problem.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-05-20**:
OK. I will post screenshots later.

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-05-20**:
OS:Ubuntu 12.04LTS
I launch rosversion ros........ it says 
This case is launch turtlebot_bring 3d_sensor.launch
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkdtlzh6082p357/Screenshot%20from%202013-05-21%2016_13_29.png

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-05-20**:
I am running rviz locally on the turtlebot.